# using deep link to open mail app in react native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

I am trying to find out what the deeplink url is for the mail app in ios.
I have an alert that is opening and then when a user presses 'ok', they will be redirected to the default mail app.

```
const openEmailApp = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      Linking.openURL('mailto:');
    }
};
```

I imagine the mail app deeplink is something like

```
mailapp://
```

```
Alert.alert('Verify Email address', 'Press Ok to open mail app', [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Menu'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    {text: 'OK', onPress: {openEmailApp}},
  ]);
```

I am also getting an error for illegal cb function.

```
cb is not a function. (In 'cb(value)', 'cb' is an instance of Object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were wrapping openEmailApp inside curly brackets. Write it like this

```
Alert.alert('Verify Email address', 'Press Ok to open mail app', [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Menu'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    {text: 'OK', onPress: openEmailApp },
  ]);
```

Comment: the syntax inside openEmailApp function is correct. Simply add the email address after mailto it should work.

Comment: Yes that is a placeholder. How do I just open the mail app and not send a mail? Do you know what the email app link is? Might be something like mailapp://

Comment: @JasonBeedle Checkout these [Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#built-in-url-schemes)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you can use the URL scheme `message://` to open the Apple Mail app.

By using `Linking.canOpenURL('message://')` you can test if the Mail app is installed.

And `Linking.openURL('message://')` will open the Mail inbox.

For this to work, you need to make sure that `message` is set under  `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your `Info.plist`.

```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>message</string>
    </array>
```

...along with any other schemes you need such as `mailto`.